# Exporting data from a Plot3D

Tags: plotting, export

In Maple, I can get data from a plot3d like this,

```
restart;
Eq1:=diff(u(eta,t),t)=diff(u(eta,t),eta$2);
BCs := {u(0,t)=sin(t), u(10,t)=0};
ICs := {u(eta,0)=0};
sys:={Eq1};
pds:= pdsolve(sys,ICs union BCs,numeric,time=t,range=0..10);
p1:= pds:-plot3d(u(eta,t),t=0..35,eta=0..10,grid=[360,360]):
```

Here is the command for exporting data from  plot `p1`

```
A:= op([1,3],p1):
  a,b:= op(op([1,1],p1)):
  c,d:= op(op([1,2],p1)):
  m:= rhs(rtable_dims(A)[1]):
  n:= rhs(rtable_dims(A)[2]):
  for i from 1 to m do
   for j from 1 to n do
     X:= ((m-i)*a + (i-1)*b)/(m-1);
     Y:= ((n-j)*c + (j-1)*d)/(n-1);
     fprintf("C:/tcdata/SL1.txt",
         "%f  %f  %f\n",Y,X,A[i,j]);
   end do
  end do:
  close("C:/tcdata/SL1.txt"):
```

This gives me data in the desired format, which I can later use in another software. The format is

```
0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
0.097493  0.000000  0.102694
0.194986  0.000000  0.200925
0.292479  0.000000  0.294693
0.389972  0.000000  0.383998
0.487465  0.000000  0.468841
0.584958  0.000000  0.549221
0.682451  0.000000  0.625138
0.779944  0.000000  0.696593
0.877437  0.000000  0.763584
..............
```

How can I get data from `Plot3D` in the same format (see above) in Mathematica?

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];

pdeset = {Derivative[1, 0][U][t, x] == Derivative[0, 2][U][t, x]}

ics = {U[0, x] == 0};

bcs = {U[t, 0] == Sin[t], U[t, 10] == 0};    

bcAll = Flatten[{ics, bcs}, 1];    

sol = NDSolve[{pdeset, bcAll}, {U}, {t, 0, 35}, {x, 0, 10}];

Plot3D[(U /. First@sol)[t, x],  {t, 0, 35}, {x, 0, 10},
 PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: It isn't clear to me whether you want to export a table of values from Mathematica (as you did in your Maple code) or a 3D plot as an image. Please clarify.

Comment: @m_goldberg I want to export data values from `Plot3D` in Mathematica as I did in Maple.

Comment: `Export["data.txt", output, "Table"];`

Comment: @mrz What exactly we are exporting here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No need to extract the points from the plot as you have the generating function already, unless this is exactly what you want

```
Export["pts-plot.dat", Plot3D[(U /. First@sol)[t, x], {t, 0, 35}, {x, 0, 10}, 
PlotRange -> All][[1, 1]], "Table"]
```

Otherwise, use `Table` or its parallel version to obtain as many points as you want:

```
pts = Flatten[ParallelTable[{t, x, (U /. First@sol)[t, x]}, {t, 0, 35, 0.5}, {x,0, 10, 0.5}], 1]:
Export["pts.dat", pts, "Table"]
```

Comment: Thanks, I learned "indexing" the Plot-object to get the points. tricky!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Yes, very useful to access different features of Plot-object

Comment: Both approaches worked just fine for me. The first one is what I was looking for. Thx

Answer (score 3):

If you name your Plot

```
pic=Plot3D[(U /. First@sol)[t, x],  {t, 0, 35}, {x, 0, 10},PlotRange -> All]
```

you can pick the plotted points with

```
p=Flatten[Cases[bild, _GraphicsComplex , Infinity][[;; , 1]], 1]
Show[pic, Graphics3D[Point[p]]]
```

[image]

```
Export["data.txt", p, "Table"]
```